# Is this cell decomposition about projective space holds?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, projective-space

Recall that if $V$ is a vector space over some field $k (=\mathbb R,\mathbb C,\mathbb H \text {(quaternions)} $) then a [projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space) can be thought of as the set of lines through the origin of $V$. Suppose dim$_{R} (k)=d$ then is it true that

> $k\mathbb P^n$ can be obtained from $k\mathbb P^{n-1}$ by attaching a $dn$-cell to $k \mathbb P^{n-1}$.

I have proved it in case $k=\mathbb R$ but i am having trouble for other fields $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb H$.

Comment: If you change $d$ to be the dimension of the field $k$ over $\mathbb R$, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks edited,how does one show this?

Comment: Essentially in the same way as one shows the real case! I'd imagine at least the complex case is done in sensible textbooks that treat CW-complexes (and if you do that one the quaternionic case is similar)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: I am having trouble in understanding even the complex case (at least from Hatcher's book).Could you sketch or give some reference?

Comment: Googling "cw structure complex projective space" lands me at http://www.math.ru.nl/~mgroth/teaching/htpy13/Section07.pdf , which gives the details.